extracting cell contents using Numbers
I have a Number's file.  Each row has details for a different person.  One of the columns is their email address.  How can I extract these addresses and put them in a simple, unformatted text file - each address on a new line?

Create a new Numbers file and create a single table in it with only one column. Copy & paste the email addresses from the original Numbers file to the new Numbers file with one table of one column. Then, while within the new Numbers file, go to File > Export To and select CSV and then click on Save.
The below screenshot shows, as an example, a Numbers file with a single table of single column with randomly generated ten email addresses and the CSV file (then opened by TextEdit) that comes out when that Numbers file is exported as described above.
The Numbers file is created and exported using Numbers 14.0 under macOS Sonoma 14.4.1.


Hi, thanks for your suggestion.  I have followed your instructions but I still have a file that is 'formatted' (i.e. each address is in a separate (single-column) spreadsheet box.  I'm wanting to have each email on a separate line in plain text...?

@Dan - with which program you open csv file?

Textedit (on the Mac)

@Dan Not sure exactly where but you are probably doing a small mistake somewhere in the process. I will update my answer to show a screenshot of the example files created as described in the answer. Hopefully those might help.

@Alper - Hi and thanks so much for your extra info.  It looks like my problem maybe that my MacBook can only run OSX 12.7.4...  (I've tried doing exactly as your extra info suggests)

@Dan No problem. Pls also note that, I get the same result (displayed in the screenshot in my answer above) when I copy and paste the email addresses from the Numbers table direcly to a text file.
